# Error after installing font using otftotfm - "unknown version of OS/2 table (0004)"

Tags: fonts, otftotfm

I want to use an open-source .TTF font in my document named Lato. It's a family of fonts, that can be downloaded free of charge at http://www.latofonts.com/.

I tried using `otftotfm` with the following parameters to install the font:

```
otftotfm -a -e ec  -fkern -fliga --verbose --vendor Lato Lato-Regular.ttf T1--Lato-Regular
```

Afterwards I made a small `fd` file called `t1lato.fd`, with these contents:

```
\ProvidesFile{t1lato.fd}
   [2014/06/07 scalable font definitions for T1/Lato.]

\DeclareFontFamily{T1}{Lato}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{m}{n}{<-> T1--Lato--Regular}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{m}{it}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{m}{sl}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{m}{sc}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{b}{n}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{b}{it}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{b}{sl}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{b}{sc}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{bx}{n}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{bx}{it}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{bx}{sl}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{bx}{sc}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{sb}{n}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{sb}{it}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}

\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{l}{n}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{l}{it}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{l}{sl}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{Lato}{l}{sc}{<->ssub * Lato/m/n}{}

\endinput
```

(Honestly, I just want to use the regular roman font, just for the sake of completion I mention a variety of different font shapes.)

I made a small test file, `lato.tex` to test the result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=10mm,bottom=10mm,left=10mm,right=10mm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{microtype}

\pdfmapfile{Lato.map}

\renewcommand\rmdefault{Lato}
\renewcommand\sfdefault{Lato}

\begin{document}

aaa \large  bbb
\end{document}
```

The above file produces a fatal error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file .../.texlive2013/texmf-var/fonts/
truetype/Lato/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf): unknown version of OS/2 table (0004)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I can't find much related to the error. Neither on TeX.SX, nor on google (I'm just getting results related to issues with Macintosh computers). The result is strange; I always got instant result for any other fonts I installed. I'd still like to use this font, but I'm not sure how. Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

I'd like to avoid LuaLaTeX and the `fontspec` package where possible; otherwise I'd have to change a dozen fonts in my main document to use `fontspec` instead (I installed those fonts with the same method without any problems).

Comment: A distribution of already packaged Lato fonts for `pdflatex` is already available in TeX Live (`\usepackage{lato}`).

Comment: And also in `MiKTeX`.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the suggestion. Almost thought that would work but I'm running into new errors in the main document. The `lato` package seems to conflict with my own fonts, declared through e.g. `\pdfmapfile{GillSans.map}`.

Comment: You should use `\pdfmapfile{+GillSans.map}`; the declaration you're using disregards the standard `pdftex.map`.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue. Is it worth looking into the issue of the OS/2 table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX Live (and also MiKTeX, according to Bernard) feature a complete distribution of the Lato fonts, both as Type1 and TrueType.

For `pdflatex` (Type1 fonts), just do

```
\usepackage{lato}
```

With XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, just load the fonts with `fontspec`.

Debugging the error by `otftotfm` might be quite hard, but since we already have the fonts package, it doesn't seem to be useful. Notice that `otftotfm` is geared towards OpenType fonts, rather than TrueType ones.

---

Warning: if you add manually a map file to your document, you should prefix the file name with `+` or `=` (the difference is that `+` overrides entries that may already be present in `pdftex.map`, whilst `=` will ignore duplicate entries in the additional map file), so

```
\pdfmapfile{+GillSans.map}
```

for example.

Answer (score 8):

I just bumped into the same error, and I really wanted to know what's going on, so here is (hopefully) a reproducible test case. (For some reason, in this test, Lato didn't give this error).

While looking for this, I found some nice little applications called `ttfencinst` and `afmtoenc` (via [CyrTeX-ru@vsu.ru Mailing List Archive: Re: Новые версии шрифтов Хартия и Эвристика](https://info.vsu.ru/Lists/CyrTeX-ru/Message/9328.html?altLanguage=english) and [CyrTeX-ru@vsu.ru Mailing List Archive: Re: Re: Стоит ли юзать XeTeX, или рано ещё?](https://info.vsu.ru/Lists/CyrTeX-ru/Message/8541-P.txt)), which I'll be using here.

Here is the first part of the test: downloading a font and the applications, runing FontForge (version 20100501) to convert, and running them up to failure, provided as `bash` commands (tested on an old Ubuntu 11.04):

```bash
mkdir -p /tmp/fontest
cd /tmp/fontest

# Lato passes this without a problem
# wget -nc http://www.latofonts.com/download/Lato2OFL.zip
wget -nc http://dl.1001fonts.com/pecita.zip
unzip -n pecita.zip
if [ ! -f Pecita.ttf ]; then
  fontforge -lang=ff -c 'Open($1); Generate($2)' Pecita.otf Pecita.ttf
fi

# this contains `ttfencinst` script, that uses `afmtoenc`
wget -nc http://litwr.narod.ru/afmtoenc-1.05.zip
unzip -n afmtoenc-1.05.zip
cd afmtoenc-1.05/
if [ ! -f afmtoenc ] ; then
  make # many warnings, but compiles
fi

# ttfencinst will only work with font in its directory
if [ ! -f Pecita.ttf ]; then
  cp ../Pecita.ttf .
fi
# call ttfencinst with a path specification:
PATH="$PWD:$PATH" ./ttfencinst Pecita.ttf T1

# here it should fail with:
# (./Pecita-T1.tex{/media/disk/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updm
# ap/pdftex.map} [1] ){Pecita-T1.enc}<Pecita.ttf
# !pdfTeX error: pdftex (file Pecita.ttf): unknown version of OS/2 table (0004)
```

At this point, I found [Re: [Fontforge-devel] wrong OS/2 table value in fonts generated by FontForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/fontforge/mailman/message/29305091/):

> > I checked those particular fonts, because I had problems to get them
> >     displayed with my ereader. If I'm not getting it wrong, it seems that
> >     the Adobe software from the ereader is not able to understand version 4
> >     of OS/2 tables.
> >
> > Can I downgrade version 4 to 1 in OS/2 table version? What could I loose?
>
> You can set it from OS/2 tab in font info dialog, but I'd be surprised
>   if it was the problem.

The only problem here was finding where this "font info dialog" is, because the http://fontforge.github.io/fontinfo.html says only "The Font Info dialog is available from all views."; this got cleared up thanks to [Design With FontForge : The Final Output, Generating Font Files](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/The_Final_Output_Generating_Font_Files.html):

> Open the "Font Info" window from the "Element" menu.

So here is how Pecita.ttf looks like in FontForge's "Font Info":

[image: fforge.png]

See how OS/2 version by default is 4? That is the "(0004)" in "unknown version of OS/2 table (0004)". So just set this to 3 from the drop down menu, and hit OK. Then, do NOT hit File/Save (or Save As), that wants to save in FontForge's internal format (`.sfd`); what you want is File/Generate Fonts... - and make sure filename is Pecita.ttf before you save (say Yes when warnings appear, and "Save" (anyway) on "Errors Detected" after validation).

Now make sure you've replaced the Pecita.ttf in the `afmtoenc-1.05/` folder (you might want to do the save from FontForge directly there to begin with); and re-run the script above again (it should not download etc if it finds the files existing) - this time you should get a succesful closing message:

```
(./Pecita-T1.tex{/media/disk/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updm
ap/pdftex.map} [1] ){Pecita-T1.enc}<Pecita.ttf></media/disk/texlive/2014/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></media/disk/texlive
/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt12.pfb></media/disk/t
exlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt8.pfb>
Output written on Pecita-T1.pdf (1 page, 50909 bytes).
Transcript written on Pecita-T1.log.
```

... and you can look at the table in the generated Pecita-T1.pdf:

[image: Pecita-T1.png]

Apparently, most OTF fonts (these days?) have a OS/2 table of version 4, which is preserved if you use FontForge to convert them to TTF, and so that apparently makes `pdftex` barf; thankfully, the solution with downgrading the table version in FontForge seems easy enough - as long as one knows where to look `:)`

Well, hope this helps someone,
Cheers!

Comment: This was a great help, thanks for investigating! One gotcha I had to get around is that FontForge will silently upgrade the font back to version 4 if either of the following features is used: Use typo metric (on the OS/2 Metrics tab), Weight, width, slope only (on the OS/2 Misc. tab). (I discovered these by reading the source.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, also at @ReubenThomas. This was a real life saver!

Comment: Thanks @sdaau! Besides changing the font, is there an update of PDFtex to be expected in the future? Because it is 2023 and I am running into the same issue with another font.