# PDFTeX Custom TTF font OS/2 version incorrect though I changed the font's OS/2 version

Tags: fonts, pdftex

When I compile my `.tex` file in TeXWorks, PDFLaTex tells me that my OS/2 table version is 0004, and therefore incompatible. Thing is, I tried generating the font (In FontForge) as OS/2 versions 0001 through 0003, but TexWorks still insists that the OS/2 version is 0004. Every time I re-generate the font, I create a new .tfm file (through the `.ttf` file through ttf2tfm, though I tried `.pfb`/`.afm` (with afm2tfm) and otf).

Still, it gives me the same message of

```
!pdfTeX error: miktex-pdftex.exe (file ./Lotrazian.ttf): unknown version of OS/2 table (0004)
```

FontForge insists that the OS/2 version is 3 (or 2 or 1...): 
[image: Lotrazian is OS/2 Version 3!]

I tried the instructions from [this guide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196014/error-after-installing-font-using-otftotfm-unknown-version-of-os-2-table-000), but to no avail.

My working environment (with the font files) can be found [here](http://lotrazi.github.io/Lotrazian.zip)

I am not sure if this is a PDFTeX, FontForge, or personal issue, but I would appreciate any help I can get

> Update: I opened the .ttf file in FontForge itself, and there it says
>   it is OS/2 Version 4. I corrected it and saved the file again, but it
>   didn't work. Looks like this is FontForge's problem

Comment: I haven't seen that behavior in FontForge before. Maybe it is platform-specific, or transient during a recent change.

Comment: @RobtAll I’m raising my concerns on the issues tab of their github page, if anything works from there on I’ll close up this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196014/error-after-installing-font-using-otftotfm-unknown-version-of-os-2-table-000#comment786544_225089) that I missed, having "**Really Use typo metric**" (on the OS/2 Metrics tab), and "**Weight, width, slope only**" (on the OS/2 Misc. tab) will silently upgrade the OS/2 version back to version 4. 
Make sure to check this if you have this problem!

Comment: Although that's not a TeX thing, it is worth knowing. And, that's why I never saw the problem.