# How can I make PDFTeX work with a TrueType font that uses OS/2 table version 4?

Tags: fonts, otftotfm, autoinst

I converted a TrueType font with `autoinst` and `otftotfm`, updated the map files and the file name database, as I am doing when converting other fonts. However when loading and trying to compile a document, I receive the following error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file MYFONT.ttf): unknown version of OS/2 table (0004)
```

When looking for solutions, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225089/156791 comes up and it seems this is a known issue of PDFtex for several years. Can I make PDFtex work with a TrueType-Font that uses an OS/2 table of version 4 or do I really have to manually modify all fonts to use the other table version? Will I loose any features from the font?

Comment: sorry I can't answer your actual question, but isn't it easier to use lualatex?

Comment: I don't think that a current pdftex can use the font. You could ask on the pdftex list https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/pdftex if an extension is possible and if someone is willing to implement it, but as texlive 2023 has just been released you probably would get an update only with texlive 2024 (perhaps earlier in miktex).

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle well for me personally yes, but I am maintaining a company internal package which contains our Corporate Font which got updated lately. And there are quite some people relying on PDFtex.

Comment: What a pity @UlrikeFischer but with that knowledge I will look into the way of manually changing to OS/2 version 3. Does anyone no of anything that this will break?

Comment: don't you have an otf version of the font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer unfortunately not. Until the last release the font was published as OTF but that got replaced by TTF recently.

Comment: The [OS/2 table spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/os2) contains a section "Version differences" for each field in the table. From that page it seems the differences between version 3 and version 4 are very minor. Version 4 allows a extra Unicode ranges and some others are rearranged. Furthermore version 4 allows oblique glyphs for example. However in general, from a Euro-centric perspective, I don't think you will break anything relevant when going back to version 3.